# How to get Rs symbol in textboxs t

Tags: c#, vba, selenium-webdriver

I have used this code, but the output shows $ symbol . I need to change it to Rs format. is it possible.? Please give an idea to change this code

```
private void textBox5_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Double value;

    if (Double.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out value))
    {
        textBox5.Text = String.Format(
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
            "{0 :C2}", 
            value);
    }
    else
    {
        textBox5.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking  for *Indian Rupee sign*, change culture to *Indian*:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(vs.71).aspx

```
 // ₹ 123.45 
 textBox5.Text = String.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN"), "{0 :C2}", 123.45);
```

**Edit**: when trying to find out the culture required (*Sri-Lankan* in your case) you can use *Linq*:

```
  var cultures = CultureInfo
    .GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    .Where(culture => culture.EnglishName.Contains("Sri"))
    .Select(culture => String.Format("{0} {1}", culture.Name, culture.EnglishName));

  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, cultures));
```

I've got `si-LK Sinhala (Sri Lanka)` as an output, so it seems that *Sri-Lankan Rupees* requires

```
  textBox5.Text = String.Format(new CultureInfo("si-LK"), "{0 :C2}", 123.45);
```

Comment: thank you sir,, If i need to change to Sri-Lankan Rupees ??

Comment: @Rifath Apps: in case of *Sri-Lankan Rupee* you, probably, want `"si-LK"` culture (see my edit)

Comment: Its helped a lot.. Thank you @DmitryBychenko